What size copper tubing do I need for a 7/16 flare nut?
I recently purchased a split AC unit (product sheet).
On the product sheet it is said that it is supposed to use 1/4" liquid and 1/2" gas pipes. I opened the unit and I found two couples of flare nuts inside - small ones marked 7/16 and big ones marked 3/8.
I got a little confused so I asked the AI and this is what it told me:

A 3/8-inch flare nut typically corresponds to a 3/8-inch OD copper tube.
A 7/16-inch flare nut typically corresponds to a 1/2-inch OD copper tube.

Which confused me even more, because 1/2 is greater than 3/8, but it's telling me that my smaller nut is supposed to go on a tube that's larger than my bigger nut?
Then I inverted the question but still got more confusing answers:

1/4" copper tube: You would need a flare nut that is 1/4" with a 3/16" thread size.
1/2" copper tube: You would need a flare nut that is 1/2" with a 1/4" thread size.

Can you help me out with sizing my copper tubing?
PS: I know you will be tempted to tell me to just call a professional to do the install but fortunately or not I'm going to have to DIY it.

go to store with the part and check

An important question: Is the compressor unit pre-charged?

Does the unit already have flare caps on each unit? That's how they usually come, and you use those with the 1/4 and 1/2 lines. You flare them on before torquing the lines and then vacuuming the system.

Typically these units are manufactured with metric size tubes and fittings. The instructions are often then translated into english and sizing gets, "lost in translation". I have found this when installing mini split units myself. Forget about what is printed on the fittings.
The size of your particular system as well as the distance of each line run, will dictate what size liquid and gas lines are to be used from the evaporator (wall units) to the outside compressor/ condenser.
It is virtually impossible to confuse which line is gas or liquid as the sizes are vastly different. However the exact size for your installation need to be determined by experts in the field.  I suppose you could just purchase what size fits, however that does not mean that the lines are properly sized for optimal performance of the system.
You asked to not be told to consult a professional, however tech support or professional guidance in choosing the proper size lines is advised.

I am not concerned with confusing gas and liquid pipes, rather than ordering the correct diameter pipes, as they did not come included with the unit, only the flare nuts did, and their markings don't seem to match the tube sizes on the product sheet.

That is my point.  You need to contact the manufacturer and have them send the correct size lines for the size unit you are installing.  The lines need to be sized to the unit not to the fittings.  Then get the correct size fitting for the lines you need.  You may need an adapter then to connect the lines to the components.  Guessing on the size of the lines will make the system function with less efficiency.

But the fittings came included with the unit, why would I need to get different fittings? I assumed that I need to size the pipes to the fittings that came with the unit because it seems like the most trustworthy source of information but I don't see 7/16 pipes for sale. I doubt I'll be able to contact the manufacturer, since I got it from a chain of resellers, but I'll try.

My units came with multiple size fittings, but the correct size lines were determined by the size of the wall units and the compressor they were getting attached to as well as the length of the run between the two.   This should have been figured out before purchase.  Are you units second hand?

No, it's new and it only has one couple of fittings per line, so they should be the correct size?

Maybe...maybe not.  There are variables in play here.  You aske that you not be directed to the professionals, so I have nothing further.

Pipe sizes and tubing sizes are usually two different animals.  You are probably dealing with tube sizing, instead of pipe sizes.  Just something to confuse us.  Hopefully they do not add pipe and tube sizes also for both lines.  If the nuts fit in the holes, take them to a plumbing store/shop for the right sizes.
